# Get the Survey ID from a Qualtrics survey when a site intercept triggers?

Tags: qualtrics

When you receive a survey from Qualtrics via site intercept, is there a way to find out (via searching on the HTML on it, or on the 'message' event) which survey you are receiving?

If that is not the case, is there a way to modify a question's JS to send this information?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things you could do:

1) Add the embedded data field SurveyID at the top of your survey flow and don't assign a value to it. SurveyID is a unique identifier Qualtrics assigns to a survey. You can then pipe it into a question or JavaScript as ${e://Field/SurveyID}.  You could also pass it to web service that uses the Qualtrics REST API to return information about the survey such as survey name, etc.

2) Under Survey Options, you can change the Meta Description to be the survey name.  Then if you look at the source html there will be a tag like:

```
<meta name="description" content="This is the Survey Name">
```

Comment: I tried the first option and it worked! Exactly what I needed, to get the Survey ID from the receiving end. I'd just want to add one point to the people seeing this later on: to get the value of the embedded data field, you have to access it like this `"${e://Field/SurveyID}"` *with* the quotation marks.

Comment: If piping into a JavaScript you have to put it in quotes because the pipe ${e://Field/SurveyID} gets replaced with a string value (SV_xxxxxxxxxx) by the Qualtrics server when it sends the page to the browser.  If you were piping into a question or using it as a web service parameter you wouldn't use quotes.